# What is causing this "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" error with glmmLASSO?

Tags: r

I am using the glmmLASSO package in R to run a penalized regression. As far as I can tell I am using the exact same syntax as the demo that comes with the package, so I am stumped as to why I am getting an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I know that there are many questions on the site about this error, but the ones I read didn't seem to help.)

(I am using the first method for determining lambda that the soccer demo suggests.)

```
library(glmmLasso)
library(MASS)
library(lme4)

lambda <- seq(500,0,by=-5)
BIC_vec<-rep(Inf,length(lambda))
```

Start by fitting a good starting model. The outcome is continuous, as are all of the predictors.

```
PQL<-glmmPQL(Rating~1+AbrCon+BeaUgl+BigSma+DanSaf+DelRug+ExcCal+FasSlo+GooBad+HapSad+HarSof+HrsMel+HeaLig+InhFre+IntUni+MasFem+OrdUni+PasAct+PleUnp+ReaFan+ShaRou+SimCom+SolNon+StrWea+StrDis+TenRel,random = list(~1|Subject,~1|Nonword, ~1|Image), family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data=data)
```

Use these results as starting values in the upcoming LASSO regression.

```
Delta.start<-c(as.numeric(PQL$coef$fixed),rep(0,6),as.numeric(t(PQL$coef$random$Subject)),as.numeric(t(PQL$coef$random$Nonword)),as.numeric(t(PQL$coef$random$Image)))
Q.start<-as.numeric(VarCorr(PQL)[c(2, 4, 6)])
Q.start<-as.matrix(Q.start)
```

Then use glmmLasso to find the lambda value that results in the lowest BIC.

```
family = gaussian(link = identity)

    for(j in 1:length(lambda)){print(paste("Iteration ", j,sep=""))

      glm1 <-
 try(glmmLasso(Rating~1+AbrCon+BeaUgl+BigSma+DanSaf+DelRug+ExcCal+FasSlo+GooBad+HapSad+
HarSof+HrsMel+HeaLig+InhFre+IntUni+MasFem+OrdUni+PasAct+PleUnp+ReaFan+
ShaRou+SimCom+SolNon+StrWea+StrDis+TenRel, rnd = list(Subject=~1, Nonword=~1, Image=~1),  family = family, data = data, 
lambda=lambda[j],switch.NR=T,final.re=TRUE,control=list(start=Delta.start,q_start=Q.start)), silent=TRUE)  
      if(class(glm1)!="try-error")
      { BIC_vec[j]<-glm1$bic}}
```

But this is where I start running into problems, each iteration has this error:

```
[1] "Iteration 1"
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
[1] "Iteration 2"
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Edit: I have added some sample data using random values here: https://pastebin.com/zP9tgjEH

Comment: Can you provide the exact warning messages you're getting? Here's what I get on the first two iterations: `Warning messages:
1: In est.glmmLasso.RE(fix = fix, rnd = rnd, data = data,  ... :
  Cluster variable should be specified as a factor variable!
2: In if (s > 1) warning("Random slopes are not standardized back!") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. I get the first warning once, and then every iteration produces a repeat of the second warning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The error I get is the exact warning I get. I should have noted that I converted all of the clustering variables to factors, and standardized the predictors.

Answer (score 0):

Does `glm1` have more than one class? If so , `if(class(glm1)!="try-error") 
 {BIC_vec[j]<-glm1$bic}}` would return that warning.

As a simple example of what might be happening:

```
x = glm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)

class(x)
```

> ```
> [1] "glm" "lm"
> ```

```
class(x) != "lm"
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE  FALSE
> ```

The model object has two classes, but `if` only takes one condition, so it uses the first one and adds a warning about it. The output below is not what we intended, because we want the condition to be true if *all* of the classes are not `lm`.

```
if(class(x) != "lm") "Is not class lm" else "Is class lm"
```

> ```
> [1] "Is not class lm"
> Warning message:
> In if (class(x) != "lm") "Is not class lm" else "Is class lm" :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> ```

So, instead, check whether all of the classes are not `lm`. This returns a single logical value and gives the desired result.

```
all(class(x) != "lm"))
```

> ```
> [1] FALSE
> ```

```
if(all(class(x) != "lm")) "Is not class lm" else "Is class lm"
```

> ```
> [1] "Is class lm"
> ```

In your case, the code would be:

```
if(all(class(glm1) != "try-error"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and detailed reply! However, `glm1` does only have one class. `class(glm1)` returns `[1] "glmmLasso"`.