# Error in if (class(networks) == "matrix") from a function

Tags: r, function, debugging, error-handling

I have a function which computes a centrality index for the nodes in a network or matrix.
Here is the function:

```
library(igraph) #load package igraph
centrality <- function (networks, type = c("indegree", "outdegree", "freeman", 
    "betweenness", "flow", "closeness", "eigenvector", "information", 
    "load", "bonpow"), directed = TRUE, lag = 0, rescale = FALSE, 
    center = FALSE, coefname = NULL, ...) 
{
    if (is.null(directed) || !is.logical(directed)) {
        stop("'directed' must be TRUE or FALSE.")
    }
    else if (length(directed) != 1) {
        stop("The 'directed' argument must contain a single logical value only.")
    }
    else if (directed == FALSE) {
        gmode <- "graph"
    }
    else {
        gmode <- "digraph"
    }
    objects <- checkDataTypes(y = NULL, networks = networks, 
        lag = lag)
    centlist <- list()
    for (i in 1:objects$time.steps) {
        if (type[1] == "indegree") {
            cent <- degree(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                cmode = "indegree", rescale = rescale, ...)
        }
        else if (type[1] == "outdegree") {
            cent <- degree(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                cmode = "outdegree", rescale = rescale, ...)
        }
        else if (type[1] == "freeman") {
            cent <- degree(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                cmode = "freeman", rescale = rescale, ...)
        }
        else if (type[1] == "betweenness") {
            cent <- betweenness(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                rescale = rescale, ...)
        }
        else if (type[1] == "flow") {
            cent <- flowbet(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                rescale = rescale, ...)
        }
        else if (type[1] == "closeness") {
            cent <- closeness(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                rescale = rescale, ...)
        }
        else if (type[1] == "eigenvector") {
            cent <- evcent(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                rescale = rescale, ...)
        }
        else if (type[1] == "information") {
            cent <- infocent(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                rescale = rescale, ...)
        }
        else if (type[1] == "load") {
            cent <- loadcent(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                rescale = rescale, ...)
        }
        else if (type[1] == "bonpow") {
            cent <- bonpow(objects$networks[[i]], gmode = gmode, 
                rescale = rescale, tol = 1e-20, ...)
        }
        else {
            stop("'type' argument was not recognized.")
        }
        centlist[[i]] <- cent
    }
    time <- numeric()
    y <- numeric()
    for (i in 1:objects$time.steps) {
        time <- c(time, rep(i, objects$n[[i]]))
        if (is.null(centlist[[i]])) {
            y <- c(y, rep(NA, objects$n[[i]]))
        }
        else {
            if (center == TRUE) {
                centlist[[i]] <- centlist[[i]] - mean(centlist[[i]], 
                  na.rm = TRUE)
            }
            y <- c(y, centlist[[i]])
        }
    }
    if (is.null(coefname) || !is.character(coefname) || length(coefname) > 
        1) {
        coeflabel <- ""
    }
    else {
        coeflabel <- paste0(".", coefname)
    }
    if (lag == 0) {
        laglabel <- ""
    }
    else {
        laglabel <- paste0(".lag", paste(lag, collapse = "."))
    }
    label <- paste0(type[1], coeflabel, laglabel)
    dat <- data.frame(y, time = time, node = objects$nodelabels)
    dat$node <- as.character(dat$node)
    colnames(dat)[1] <- label
    attributes(dat)$lag <- lag
    return(dat)
}
```

Here is the matrix:

```
dat <- read.table(text="A B #this is edgelist
1 2
1 3
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 1", header=TRUE)
datmat <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(graph.edgelist(as.matrix(dat), directed=TRUE))) #this is the matrix
colnames(datmat) <- c("1", "2", "3") #rename the columns
```

When I applied the function to a matrix `centrality(datmat,type="flow",center=TRUE)`, it returns the error:

```
Error in if (class(networks) == "matrix") { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

So far none of the following solutions I found works for me: [How can I fix the VECM warning message of "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325114/how-can-i-fix-the-vecm-warning-message-of-the-condition-has-length-1-and-only)

[What is causing this "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" error with glmmLASSO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957268/what-is-causing-this-the-condition-has-length-1-and-only-the-first-element-wi)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `if (inherits(networks, "matrix"))` ?

Comment: What do you see from `print(class(networks))`?  I suspect `networks` has more than one class, in which case you will need `if ("matrix" %in% class(networks))`.  Or @BenBolker's simultaneously posted suggestion, which I feel is more elegant than mine.

Comment: @BenBolker I tried that to another function and it didn't work. Can you show me more details about how to use `inherits` in my `centrality` function? I don't know where to put it in the code

Comment: @Limey Thanks for the hint. The matrix has two classes `matrix` and `array` but can you provide more directions as for where to insert `if ("matrix" %in% class(networks))` in my code?

Comment: Can you show us the results of `traceback()` (run immediately after getting the error)? I don't see `class(networks) == "matrix"` in the code you've posted, so either it's elsewhere in your code or it's somewhere in some package's code.